# Exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurs while registering plugin in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I am getting the following error when trying to register a plugin in CRM 2013:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Assembly can not be loaded.

**DETAIL**

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Create(Entity entity)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.CreateCore(Entity entity)
   at PluginRegistrationTool.RegistrationHelper.RegisterPlugin(CrmOrganization org, CrmPlugin plugin)
   at PluginRegistrationTool.PluginRegistrationForm.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Check if you signed the asembly.

Comment: yes i have signed it.. :) but not working still

Comment: The SDK version is for 2013?

Comment: if not online, you could try turning on server tracing? can you post the detail as well?

Comment: Yes it is on-premesis and i posted the details above :)

Comment: @Sxntk we have crm 2013 on-premesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solved**

Actually it was dll file of custom workflow written in C# not plugin dll...
This exception was thrown because , i was registering it on disk. Later i tried it to register on database and it worked fine...
**I suggest all of you to register your plugins on disk and workflows on database.**
hope this will solve if anyone face this problem in future.

dlls are registered using plugin registration tool. you can find in link ([download](https://dynamicday.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/crm-2013-plugin-registration-tool-connect-to-crm-online/))

Comment: Glad you solved it, for future reference, registering to database is recommended since CRM 2011. Registering to disk is kept mostly for backward compatibility with CRM 4. If you were registering to disk against crm online, i think it is not possible due to the fact the plugins need to execute in sandbox mode on crm online.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are using the older version for Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, you should use version 6. So download the latest SDK from the following link http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40321, replace your dll reference in the plugin project, rebuild and try to update the plugins.

Comment: guys if you are registering the ddl of custom workflows than you should register it on database not on disk... it will work perfect :)